# Section Title in Header with scrlayer-scrpage

Tags: header-footer, article, scrlayer-scrpage

I tried a lot, but couldn't find a solution:

Im using the package scrlayer-scrpage and the article class

```
\clearscrheadfoot
\lehead*{\textcolor{white}{\headmark}}
\lohead*{\textcolor{white}{\headmark}}
\chead*{\begin{tcolorbox}[enhanced,
            width=\textwidth,
            height=1.5cm,
            arc=0mm,
            boxrule=0mm,
            /tcb/size=minimal,
            watermark graphics=graphics/comein_header, watermark stretch=1,]
        \end{tcolorbox}
        \vspace{0.3cm}
}
```

What do I have to change, that in the top left corner the section title is displayed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunaly there is no MWE in the question.

Using `scrheadings` the header consits of 3 elements: a left-aligned, a centered and a right-aligned. The centered element overlays the left one and the right element overlays the centered element. Therefore your text (or header) width picture in the centered element overlays the left-aligned `\headmark`.

As a workaround you can use the right-aligned element:

Example:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{blindtext}% only for dummy text
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[automark]{scrlayer-scrpage}
\setlength{\headheight}{50pt}
\clearpairofpagestyles
\ohead*{\headmark\hfill}
\chead*{\textcolor{black}{\rule{\textwidth}{1.5cm}}}
\addtokomafont{pagehead}{\bfseries\color{white}}
\begin{document}
\blinddocument
\end{document}
```

Note that in one-sided printing, only right-hand pages exist, and LATEX designates these as odd pages regardless of their page number. Therefore `\rohead` (right on odd pages) or `\ohead` (outer on all pages) is enough.

You could also define a new layer for the background picture and add this new layer before the other ones.

Example:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{blindtext}% only for dummy text
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[automark]{scrlayer-scrpage}
\setlength{\headheight}{50pt}
\DeclareNewLayer[
  head,
  background,
  contents={\rule{\textwidth}{1.5cm}}
]{headerbackground}
\AddLayersAtBeginOfPageStyle{scrheadings}{headerbackground}
\AddLayersAtBeginOfPageStyle{plain.scrheadings}{headerbackground}
\clearpairofpagestyles
\ihead*{\headmark}
\chead*{\rule{0pt}{1.5cm}}
\addtokomafont{pagehead}{\bfseries\color{white}}
\begin{document}
\blinddocument
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: That worked perfectly! Thank you a lot :)